# Loading google fonts non blocking way for Google Insights

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-pagespeed

I'm trying to pass Google page speed insights, and I can't get by "Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content" because a Google Font being loaded. None of the suggestions at Google Insights seems to be applicable in this context: inlining css, using media queries, etc. I even tried to load web font asynchronously with [WebFontLoader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader)  but it still gets caught by the Insights.

I'd imagine there should be a dead simple fix without doing stupid thins e.g. setting timeout for loading a font (which for the record kind of works ;-)).

**UPDATE**

Packing a web font with Webpack apparently also works, but I'm not sure it's the 'right' solution.

Answer (score 0):

The way I resolved this "render-blocking" notice is to load the google font url with javascript / jquery.

You set for example :

`$('head').append("<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>);`

into a .js file which you will load as

```
<script src="your.js" async></script>
```

Comment: You are only making `Insights` incapable of detecting the render blocking. You are not solving the render blocking itself, but slightly aggravate it in terms of page load speed and user experience. It's like cutting the measuring tape because it made you realize the piece of furniture you just created won't fit in its designated space. That's not going to make the furniture fit.

Comment: May I disagree with you. It is not an objectif to trick Pagespeed analysis nor it tricks it the way you present it. The defered / async scripts are fast enough and simply do the job. How in your opinion dynamic font selectors work ? I don't spot an altered user experience, at least on my websites. And finally, Pagespeed is happy with it.